# Can I add a pop up drain stopper to this bathtub?

Tags: bathtub

This piece has been missing since we moved in. Bought one from Home Depot and part that screws in was way too big. Does anyone know what kind I would need? When I went back to Home Depot, it looked like the only thing that might fit this is a drain strainer, but I would rather have a pop up stopper. [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the silver drain spud ( *the silver part in your tub* )  by using  [this special tool](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004M359PC). You can replace it with one that will accept the stopper you have or any other.

You place the tool into the spud and use a crescent wrench or a screw driver thru the hole to gently turn it counter clockwise to unscrew it from the drain pipe under the tub, then install the new one in the reverse.

Use a little lube on the new treads and some plumbers putty under the flange when you put the new one in. There is a gasket under the tub between the drain pipe and the bottom of the tub, this should stay in place but be careful not to let it fall down inside the space under the tub.

Comment: What do you think was installed there previously? It wasn’t just an open drain.

Comment: My guess would be that there was an old fasioned plug that you put into the hole to allow you to fill the bath and removed to empty it.

Comment: @CFella It could be open as peter says but it could also be an internal plunger type stopper that is actuated by a lever up at the overflow escutcheon. Is there a lever or knob on it?

Comment: I was thinking there was previously a drain strainer installed there. When I was looking at different options at Home Depot, the screw in the strainer packaging looked like it may fit.